# Save Excel File with a Timestamp when Exporting a Report in SSRS 2016

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export, ssrs-2016

I've been fiddling around with SSRS 2016 and tried, without any success, to add a timestamp to the saved excel file when exporting a report. Is there a way, preferably one that isn't much of a hack, to add the date and time to the end of the exported excel file? For example. If I have a report "Rep_1," it currently saves as Rep_1.xls. What I would like it to do is to save it as Rep_1_2017_08_24_1057, or something along those lines. Any ideas will help!

Comment: are you doing this through code, or are you talking about when people click in the export dropdown in the report viewer and select to export it?

Comment: I'm talking about when you click the export dropdown in the report viewer itself.